# Remove all breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a possibility to remove **all** breakpoints in the module (might be using a shortcut) in IntelliJ IDEA IDE? Thanks.

Comment: what about this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050898/3218362

Answer (score 241, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

is using for removing all breakpoints.
Select upper breakpoint -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> -> `Remove`

On **Mac Os** use this:

```
Cmd + Shift + (Fn) + F8 on Mac OS
```

Comment: There you need to go through tabs to remove all of them.

Comment: Yes, for each type of breakpoints. In NetBeans you can remove all breakpoints in one click, but not in IDEA

Comment: I'm a little late to the party (and possibly incorrect, hence the comment vs an answer), but I think the keyboard shortcut is now Alt+F9. Ctrl+Shift+F8 doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Note it's `Cmd + Shift + (Fn) + F8` on Mac OS.

Comment: A little late to the party again, but it changed again. Now `ctrl + shift + F8` allows to remove all of them

Comment: I am an ubuntu user and ctrl+shift+F8  is not doing anything for me

Comment: `Remove` can be replaced with the `Alt` + `Delete` keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 56):

To remove all breakpoints in IntelliJ Idea press following sequence of shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>  (open Breakpoints dialog)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>                    (select all breakpoint)
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>                (remove selected breakpoints)
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>                                (confirm)

---

If you press Ctrl+Shift+F8 and your cursor is at code line with breakpoint, instead of Breakpoint dialog you get bubble with properties of a single breakpoint.

[image]

To get the Breakpoints dialog press Ctrl+Shift+F8 again.

[image]

---

Tested in IntelliJ Idea 14 Community Edition.

---

In case of Mac, follow below steps:

1. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>  (open Breakpoints dialog)
2. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>                    (select all breakpoint)
3. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>                (remove selected breakpoints)
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>                                (confirm)

Unlike <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in windows, It's <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in Mac

Comment: Pressing 'Delete' alone removes the breakpoints you've selected. No need to press 'command' along with it, unless I am missing something :)

Answer (score 49):

As an alternative, instead of removing all breakpoints, you can just mute them.  This will help in the case that you want to stop breaking on all of them. They will still exist, so you can toggle this setting again to start breaking on them.

The mute breakpoints button can be found in the Debug view (view can be toggled using View -> Tool Windows -> Debug), in the left-hand side button menu.  I attached a screenshot below.

[image: Mute breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: You can add a shortcut for this:
In Intellij press  Ctrl + SHIFT + S (Settings) -> KeyMap -> In Right Panel search "Mute Breakpoints" and insert the shortcut you like

Comment: Mines Ctrl + Alt + S for settings (Not sure if its always been the case, but it is now)

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278734/2820534) the shortcut works.
But we tend to forget the combination of keys (I do).

There exists another way to access **breakpoints window**.

[image]

Clicking on this button [image] will open breakpoints window.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of my trick to remove all breakpoints of a page:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  : select all code
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  : cut all codes
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  : paste all code

this trick removes all breakpoints at one go and **it takes less than a second**.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac you need Shift + Comand + F8

Comment: on some Keyboards that share multiple functions with F keys  it would be Shift + Command + Fn + F8; Fn for activating F mode

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+shift+f8 and select check box of which you want to remove and then press minus button in left upper corner in android studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the answer about how to remove all breakpoints with one click (or a shortcut) in Itellij IDEA - so I found this opportunity in:
Settings -> Keymap -> Debugger Actions

- there You can find "Remove All Breakpoints" and "Remove All Breakpoints In The Current File".
  You can add a shortcut or add this action on a toolbar (I prefer this
  way more).