# Ctrl+shift+F8 not working on android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to remove all the Breakpoints  in module using shortcut

```
Ctrl+shift+F8
```

but this shortcut not work on android studio 2.2 on window 10

Any help ?

thats my setting

[image]

Comment: that shortcut is to display breakpoint window, just saying

Comment: you may wanna check in preferences if nothing else is overriding this particular shortcut

Comment: this shortcut is showing nothing

Comment: @kamran did you fix your issue

Comment: @charuka still not

Comment: @kamran have you tried to assign another short keys you like to that ?

Comment: @kamran please assign a different key combination and see result. AFAI understand the only possibility seems to be one of keys are not working.

Answer (score 3):

First go to 
Settings > Keymap and search like i did and find out whats there,That's what you are looking for 
[image]

You can **reset** short keys...or **change** as you want..

[image]

Once you are done it that keys will display debug points you have.Then go to its top and click minus mark in red.All gone!

[image]

Comment: @kamran No go to your settings like in the first image and see what short key you have for it then u can use it

Comment: shortcut is Ctrl+shift+f8

Comment: @kamran for View breakpoints seems you dont have a one see that image

Comment: @kamran right click on that view break points and add keyboard shortcut and add a one you like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132396/discussion-between-kamran-and-charuka).

Answer (score 0):

To remove all breakpoints in IntelliJ Idea press following sequence of shortcuts

1. Ctrl+Shift+F8 (open Breakpoints dialog)
2. Ctrl+A (select all breakpoint)
3. Alt+Delete (remove selected breakpoints)
4. Enter (confirm)

For more details please refer below link.

[Remove all breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278663/remove-all-breakpoints-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: yes I know that Ctrl +shift  +F8 is open dialogue but its not working thats my question