# How to effectively remove all breakpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I tried various steps to remove breakpoints from Android Studio .
One of them listed in question [BreakPoint link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278663/remove-all-breakpoints-in-intellij-idea)

I followed this but , still there are some green colored with red circle remaining , what are those as seen in image below and how to remove those effectively.

[image: Image after removing breakpoint]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[image: Remove all breakpoints in android studio]

Click on red icon which is below to stop debug. you will see a window there you can remove all breakpoints.

Comment: Yes .. after that you will get this green colored dot with red circle on it

Comment: then click on minus icon in above dialog.

Comment: Hah, clicking minus is irreversible, so the breakpoint will be removed without confirm.

Answer (score 58):

```
Step 1: ctrl+shift+F8
Step 2: ctrl+A
Step 3: Click delete or Alt+delete
Step 4: done
```

Answer (score 32):

First, click on debug tab and you see a screen like this:-

[image]

Now you will see a window like this:-

[image]

From this screen you can remove breakpoints by clicking (-) button. To remove all break point first select **Java Line break** Point option and then click (-).

Answer (score 13):

[image]

In debug option there is button disable break point button this will disable all break point

Comment: I thought this will only mute the breakpoints, but NOT remove them. OP is asking how to remove BPs.

Comment: Why is this answer getting upvoted? It does absolutely NOT remove any breakpoints whatsoever.

Comment: @PankajAndroid I tried it and while it does mute breakpoints, it does not remove them. The question was how to remove them, not how to deactivate/mute/ignore them.

Answer (score 12):

**Remove all breakpoints in three simple steps:**

1. Double `Shift` (or tap the search icon in the upper right corner).
2. Search for "Remove all".
3. Click "Remove all breakpoints"
   [image]

Answer (score 11):

**My SOP:**

- select `Favorites` from the left hand edge of the screen;
- expand`Breakpoints`
- select those you wish to remove
- press `delete` or the `-` button (located at the bottom of the window)

**Alternative:**

⌘ ⇧ F8 (Mac) or Ctrl ⇧ F8 (Windows) brings up the breakpoint dialog. Highlight the breakpoints you want to remove and press the `-` button.

Answer (score 6):

Open breakpoint window short cut key using
Ctrl + shift +f8

Answer (score 5):

Pressing ctrl+shift+F8 will pop up the Breakpoints window and then you can disable/enable all break point by clicking the [check box in the Java line Breakpoints Treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A0HR.png)

Answer (score 3):

Its really easy to remove all the break points.

1. Run -> View BreakPoints... (OR)  Ctrl + shift +f8
   [image]
2. BreakPoints dialog opens.

[image]

3. To **remove all break points** uncheck the root (Ctrl+A and Delete) or to **remove individual break points** uncheck the individuals.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this image for what it means:

[image]

Following the [intellij docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/enabling-disabling-and-removing-breakpoints.html#d2018909e89) it says:

- To remove a breakpoint permanently, do one of the following:

  - On the main menu, choose Run | View Breakpoints or `Ctrl+Shift+F8`.
  - Select the desired break point and click `-` button
  - If all breakpoints from certain group need to be deleted:

    - Select the group on the left side of the widow and Press `-` or `delete` button