# Android I/zygote64:Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver

Tags: android, garbage-collection, blocking

I'm having this problem when I debug my app. It blocks at this line and I don't know what is causing it. I could not find any answer or anyone that had the same problem. I have no clue what part of the code could cause this to happen. Do you have any ideas or have experience with this? 
I'm using
`Android Studio 3.1, 
JRE 1.8.0, 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-bit`

Comment: it's likely a signature issue caused by vendor packages... while the question is completely insufficient. I mean, how shall one answer that in a reliable manner?

Comment: Any chance that you are running android studio **NOT** as administrator? Because it may be the result of insufficient permissions

Comment: I've seen the same issue..seen it in the Android Studio 3.4 emulator as well as Samsung Galaxy Note8

Comment: I must add that this does not happen all the time, but one time out of ten maybe. So I don't think it's a problem with vendor packages nor because of runing android studio not as an admin..

Comment: This is a serious blocker for me, anyone have an insight?

Answer (score 8):

**Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver** message appears for me when I have set too many break points.

This link will help if you are looking to manage your break points.[How to effectively remove all breakpoints in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478937/how-to-effectively-remove-all-breakpoints-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by wiping out all user data from the emulator and reloaded the app. You may use this step if you are absolutely sure about loosing user data.
Go to Android Studio, then in Tools menu click on AVD Manager and select your virtual device and click on wipe data
[As may be seen in the attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUD2s.png)

Comment: This worked for me, but do you have any idea what is the cause of it, or how to prevent it?

Comment: @Valenthorpe, sorry, I don't remember exactly what caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem just now, I tried another device and the application worked usually, then I knew that the problem is in the device I used not in the code itself. To fix that, I wiped the device data and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too. But not only in debug, but also in real. As you say, one of 10-15 times when I sign in. I think the problem is derived from http connection problems. This has happened whenever I load the initial data.